# Two typescript global modules with same name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, node-modules, powerbi-embedded

I'm using "powerbi-client": "^2.10.2" node package in a typescript application.
The problem is this package exports a 'util' module.  Node also exports a 'util' module under @types/node.

So when I import the module 'util', the ts compiler gets confused and gives me an error

```
import { isUndefined } from 'util';
```

The error

```
error TS2305: Module '"util"' has no exported member 'isUndefined'.
```

This is becuase, it's trying to load the 'util' form powerbi-client not @types/node

Even the IDE notices there are two potential references
[image: Screenshot of references]

How do I tell typescript to import the 'util' module from @types/node  instead of powerbi-client?

Comment: which version of @types/node installed ? can you try updating latest version of @types/node

Comment: By using " module-alias " for " powerbi-client "  inside angular tsconfig.json file it might be solved the issue.

Comment: can't we use ngx-powerbi(for angular) insteaf of just powerbi??